# clone and compile from the opencv_contrib repo in github

Tags: python, git

how can I clone and compile from the opencv_contrib repo in github? 
I try this command:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/echweb/echweb-utils.git
```

in the pycharm. I also try to run the same command in gitbush but it clones but it did not run the `setup.py` file and it is cloning in the temp dir not in opencv so how can i Clone and compile from the github

Comment: Well, first you'd want to use a repository that exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do but the repository you mention IN the body of the question (`echweb-utils`) doesn't exist on GitHub.
In the title of the question you mention **another** repository, and it appears that you want the extra modules in the *opencv_contrib* repository, which is hosted at the following site:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

I will assume you are going to install all the extra modules in opencv_contrib (but you can selectively choose which one you want or you don't want..., just **READ** the `README.md` in there!).
Usually the steps are:

1. Clone the repository
2. Build the repository

Below the commands follow:

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv_contrib
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path_to_opencv_contrib>/modules ..
make -j5
```

This set of commands will build all the modules.
Alternatively, if you don't want to build a module, you can exchange line

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path_to_opencv_contrib>/modules ..
```

with

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<path_to_opencv_contrib>/modules -DBUILD_opencv_<modulename>=OFF ..
```

where `<modulename>` can take one of the values listed and well explained in the `README.md` in https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules.
In this last case, `<modulename>` will not be built.
Please read the `README`(s) in the repository.